# What is the difference between .dts file and .dtsi file?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree, linux

What is the difference between `.dts` file and `.dtsi` file? Is there a difference when generating device tree blobs? When to use one or the other?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Here](https://bootlin.com/pub/conferences/2021/webinar/petazzoni-device-tree-101/petazzoni-device-tree-101.pdf), as explained by Thomas Petazzoni and as point out in one of the comments by @mc110, you can find that:

1. `.dts`  <- files for board-level definitions
2. `.dtsi` <- files for included files, generally containing SoC-level
   definitions (the **i** in dts**i** stands for **Include**)

However, once the `.dtb` was created with a Device Tree Compiler, if you try to come back again obtaining a text file, only one big file will be created with all the information coming from all the `/include/` files.

Note that the **i** at the end of **dtsi** stands for **include** ( observed by @0andriy in one of the comments).

Note also that:

1. `.dts`  <- **D**evice **T**ree **S**ource
2. `.dtb` <- **D**evide **T**ree **B**lob
3. `.dtsi`  <- **D**evice **T**ree **S**ource **I**nclude